# How do you dim desktop screen 20.04 LTS?

Tags: brightness, 20.04

It's always so bright. How do you dim it so it's not hurting your eyes.

Comment: `redshift` might help you out. It's a blue-light filter that moderates brightness through hue. It works well out of the box and offers customisation . Worth a look anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `brightness-controller` which allow you to modulate brightness easily on ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```